# Is there a Bug Encyclopedia?

Tags: debugging, reference, wiki

Has anyone developed an encyclopedia or wiki of software bugs, either bug types (off-by-one, buffer overflow, etc.) or even just famous bugs (Grace Hopper's moth, the Arianne rocket failure, etc.)?

I was thinking that for tough situations, a cross-referenced encyclopedia of bug types, examples, and *symptoms* of bugs would help programmers. Especially if one could search by how the bug is manifesting itself (crashing, bad output, memory leaks, etc.).

Comment: That's StackOverflow in a nutshell: a giant list of bugs and how to fix them.

Comment: My favourite famous bug has to be the metric/imperial units confusion by NASA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is second to none:

> Top 25 Most Dangerous Programming Errors

http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/

And many more at this location...

Comment: That's not bad, although it focuses on security weaknesses rather than bugs in general.

Answer (score 1):

This one is written from the point of view of testers, but may still help:

http://www.riceconsulting.com/articles/20-most-common-software-problems.htm

Answer (score 1):

This ones kind of funny (if you have a cynical sense of humor):

> [10 Historical Software Bugs with Extreme Consequences](http://royal.pingdom.com/2009/03/19/10-historical-software-bugs-with-extreme-consequences/)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia does have articles for many general and specific bugs, such as all the ones you named:

- [off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)
- [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)
- [Grace Hopper's moth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper#Anecdotes) and the [moth itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aH96566k.jpg)
- [the Ariane rocket failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches) and more detail [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501#Launch_failure)
- [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSoftware_bugs)